# How can I run a Django 3 project with a MySQL server set on a NAS (Synology DS120J) using phpMyAdmin and MariaDB 10?

Tags: mysql, django, nas, mariadb-10.3

I appreciate the fact that the topic is quite specific, but I have been struggling to find documentation on such setup.
I am working on a Django 3 project using Python 3.9, instead of SQLite3, the application would be using a MySQL server hosted on a Synology DS120J NAS, this is done via phpMyAdmin and MariaDB 10. Basically, my objective is to run the Django 3 application from my PC (Windows 10), and the MySQL server from the NAS. Both are sharing the same local network.
Is anyone using a similar setup? If so could you please provide with some guidance?
At the moment here is the DATABASES section of the settings.py file from the application:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'gaia',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': [phpMyAdmin password],
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '[port number of the MariaDB 10 server on phpMyAdmin]'
    }
}
```

I launch the application using the following command: python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.2:[port number of the NAS]. When doing so, I get the following error message:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)").
```

I have searched for this error message but didn’t get anything very helpful as I wasn’t sure whether any of the feedbacks was involving the use of a NAS.
Could someone please help with interesting links or description?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/389987/using-nas-server-as-mysql-db-server

Comment: Your application doesn't connect to phpMyAdmin itself (which is a graphical application for administrators to manage a MySQL/MariaDB database); instead your application should connect directly through the MariaDB port. Instead of using the phpMyAdmin port (which would technically be your webserver's port, since phpMyAdmin doesn't listen for connections on its own) for `PORT`, use 3306. The `HOST` value needs to be the hostname or IP address of the NAS, not your localhost. And as a side note, you should create an application-specific user account rather than using root, as a "best practice."

Comment: @IsaacBennetch: thanks very much for your feedback, I tried that before asking here, unfortunately, it didn't produce the expected result.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: very interesting articles, thank you, it did inspire me a lot as I am now checking on the server option instead.